# int vs. BGRA union of the same size produces different results

Tags: c++, unions

Can someone explain the difference between the three below functions?

```
typedef union
{
    std::uint8_t B, G, R, A;
    std::uint32_t Colour;
} BGRA;
```

1st:

```
void Image::process_pixels(void* out, void* in)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    BGRA* pOut = (BGRA*)out;
    unsigned char* pIn = (unsigned char*)in;

    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            pOut->B = *(pIn++);
            pOut->G = *(pIn++);
            pOut->R = *(pIn++);
            pOut->A = *(pIn++);
            ++pOut;
        }
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
void Image::process_pixels(void* out, void* in)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned int* pOut = (unsigned int*)out;
    unsigned int* pIn = (unsigned int*)in;

    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            *pOut++ = *pIn++
        }
    }
}
```

3rd:

```
void Image::process_pixels(void* out, void* in)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    BGRA* pOut = (BGRA*)out;
    unsigned char* pIn = (unsigned char*)in;

    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            memcpy(pOut, pIn, sizeof(int));
            ++pOut;
            pIn += sizeof(int);
        }
    }
}
```

If I use the second or third implementation, the code works fine. Images render properly. However, if I use the first implementation, nothing renders correctly.

I can guarantee that `sizeof(BGRA) = sizeof(int)`. I can guarantee `BGRA` format for the pixels. Yet somehow I get different results..

I can't see for the life of me, the difference between the first and the last two implementations. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `memcpy` to copy a single `int`? Especially in the second version you could just as easily do `*pOut++ = *pIn++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef union
{
    std::uint8_t B, G, R, A;
    std::uint32_t Colour;
} BGRA;
```

Here `B`, `G`, `R` and `A` are 4 elements that share the same address.
You should enclose `B`, `G`, `R` and `A` inside a struct like

```
typedef union
{
    struct {
        std::uint8_t B, G, R, A;
    } Components;
    std::uint32_t Colour;
} BGRA;
```

Answer (score 1):

This union has five members. You seem to think it has only two.